# How to calculate totals on a memo Field in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have imported data from MS Access (`mdt`) file to `MS SQL`. Now I would like to test that the long text was not truncated during the import. I calculated minimum, average, maximum and sum of lengths of texts in the resulting data, like this

```
SELECT 
    MIN(DATALENGTH([LongField]))
    ,AVG(DATALENGTH([LongField]))
    ,MAX(DATALENGTH([LongField]))
    ,SUM(DATALENGTH([LongField]))
FROM TheExportedTable
```

Results:

```
0   725 7574    2156708
```

I would like to check in MS Access that the original statistics on this field was the same. The type of the field in MS Access is `memo`. How can I do it? I tried adding a calculated field, it just did not work. When I tried adding a calculated field, nothing happened...

Comment: Did the calculated field in the Access version use `Len` instead of `DATALENGTH`? ... `MIN(Len([LongField]))`

Comment: @HansUp, I was not able to create any calculated field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access you would use LEN instead of DATALENGTH:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(LEN([LongField]))
    ,AVG(LEN([LongField]))
    ,MAX(LEN([LongField]))
    ,SUM(LEN([LongField]))
FROM TheExportedTable
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am totally new to MS Access. I tried to create any calculated field, but it did not work. Where am I to enter the select statement?

Comment: Create a new query.  Open the SQL view and paste it in there.

Comment: It works, but the function `LEN` in Access gives two times smaller values, than `DATALENGTH` in MS SQL. Perhaps, the last one gives it in bytes, not in characters